# QLC+ load Project issue after set default Project

Tags: raspberry-pi

when I applay my Project as default on qlc+ and reboot the raspberry pi, it failes to start the Web Interace and the Desktop.

But the output of `sudo systemctl status qlcplus` says is running and no issues.

When I delete the autostart.qxw file in /root/.qlcplus/, it start as normal with a planc project.

I have this issue just for files with self created fictures.
Here are my Files: [Files](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1qIWyxxi4R8sJ5W4xISI1R7ZDV-_PxKQo?usp=sharing)

I use a raspberry Pi 4.

Thanks for help.